# Return response of HttpClient over REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im new to programming with .net and struggeling with a return result for my REST API on asp.net core. While checking the value "content" with the breakpoint, I checked that the value (JSON-Result from the HTTPClient) is in there, but im not able to return that value. Do you maybe have an idea, what could cause the problem? When running this code

```
   // GET: api/<MigrationDate>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://myurl.com/Api/v1/bla/bla";

        using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        });


        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       
        return (IEnumerable<string>)result;
    }
```

i get this message back:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

Comment: You have to convert your json-string (`content`) to an `IEnumerable<string>`. Change your return to something like this (If using `Newtonsoft`):
 `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(content);`

Comment: Dont use `using var client = new HttpClient(` Http Client is reentrant. Don't put it into a using block. Make a single static instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs, because you try to cast `response` to `IEnumerable<string>`. However response is from type `HttpMessageResponse` and doesn't provide a way to be casted to
`IEnumerable<string>`.

1.) Include `Newtonsoft.Json` in your project via NuGet-Marketplace (right click your project -> Manage NuGet packages)

2.) Add

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

to your respective class

3.) `content` contains the Json as string, so to get an object to work with, you have to convert this string using  `JsonConvert` from `Newtonsoft.Json`

```cs
string content = await client.GetAsync(url);
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

Depending on the response, you can then cast `json` to either `JArray`, `JObject`, `JToken` or `JValue` from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`.
For example, if you got a json array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name":"Max",
    "age": "29"
  }
]
```

you can cast `content` to `JArray` and work with it like this:

```cs
string content = await client.GetAsync(url);
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
JArray jsonArray = (JArray)json;

// print the name
string name = jsonArray.First["name"];
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says; you are trying to cast the HttpResponseMessage to a list of strings which cant be done.
Instead of using the result (HttpResponseMessage), use your content string and serialize the string into your expected
return type.

Here's an example if the content is of application/json and using Newtonsoft.Json

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync()
{
    var url = "https://myurl.com/Api/v1/bla/bla";

    using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    });


    var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(content);
}
```